# React js - unable to set state of variable properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have a functional component in React and Im having some troubles setting the state of a variable correctly. I have a Pagination component which I am using for my website and I want to know the page I am on when I click page 2 or 3 etc. I decided to set the state of the page with the handlepage function if u see below which sets the page according to which page I press. However in my other function which is onChangePage, I cannot get the correct page value when I console log which I thought should work since Ive already set the state of the page with the onchange in the pagination component. Maybe this is happening because in the pagination component I am calling both functions at the same time that causes the problem. Please tell me how to solve this, it would really help alot I need the correct value of the page in onChangePage.

```
function Build() {
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);

    const handlePage = (event, value) => {
      setPage(value);
    }

    // Function for pagination, calls redux
    const onChangePage = (name, val, page) => {

    console.log(page)
    console.log("PAGING HERE")
    dispatch(getAllPreownedCars(6, dataOptions.skip, filters, dataOptions.searchText, [val]));
  }


   return(
      <Pagination 
         count={5} 
         onClick={() => onChangePage("Price (Lowest to Highest)", "selling_Price ASC", page)} 
         page={page}
         onChange={handlePage} />
   );

}

export Build;
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, but besides that why do you have *two* separate functions responsible for handling a page change?

Comment: one of them needs to pass in 2 strings which are "Price (Lowest to Highest)", "selling_Price ASC". Is there a way to pass these 2 strings into handlePage? I tried and it didnt work for me, u can try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are asynchronous and processed *between* render cycles. You are likely executing both callbacks simultaneously, so the enqueued state update from one isn't going to be available in the other.

> Is there a way to pass these 2 strings into handlePage?

Yes, you can proxy the `onChange` event object and value to your handler. Think something along the lines of an anonymous function as follows:

```
const handlePage = (event, page, string1, string2) => {....}
...
onChange={(event, page) => handlePage(event, page, string1, string2)}
```

Below I've written `handlePage` as a curried function to first consume the two strings you want passed and returning a callback function to consume the `onChange` event object and new page value.

```
const handlePage = (name, val) => (event, page) => {
  console.log(page);
  console.log("PAGING HERE");
  setPage(page);

  dispatch(
    getAllPreownedCars(6, dataOptions.skip, filters, dataOptions.searchText, [val])
  );
};
```

Code

```
function Build() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);

  const handlePage = (name, val) => (event, page) => {
    console.log(page);
    console.log("PAGING HERE");
    setPage(page);

    dispatch(
      getAllPreownedCars(6, dataOptions.skip, filters, dataOptions.searchText, [val])
    );
  };

  return (
    <Pagination
      count={5}
      page={page}
      onChange={handlePage("Price (Lowest to Highest)", "selling_Price ASC")}
    />
  );
}
```